# Rails - Bundle not finding installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

Running "bundle exec rake" gives me the following error:

> Peters-MacBook-Air:pgproject Peter$ bundle exec rake
>   Could not find multi_json-1.0.3 in any of the sources
>   Run "bundle install" to install missing gems.

If I include a gem with a pathname in my Gemfile, it works, e.g.:

```
(in Gemfile)
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2', :path => 'il8n/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2'
```

got rid of the same error for 'rake', but listing all the gems out this way seems the wrong way to do it.  Gems are findable with "bundle show":

> Peters-MacBook-Air:pgproject Peter$ bundle show multi_json
>       /Users/Peter/code/pgproject/il8n/ruby/1.8/gems/multi_json-1.0.3

and my bundle config file appears to be pointing to the right local directory:

> Peters-MacBook-Air:pgproject Peter$ bundle config
>   Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
>
> disable_shared_gems
>     Set for your local app (/Users/Peter/code/pgproject/.bundle/config): "0"
>
> path
>     Set for your local app (/Users/Peter/code/pgproject/.bundle/config): "il8n"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try running bundle install as suggested? What resulted from that?

Comment: is your internet connected. It says it fetches metadata from a rubygems in my terminal